# void boost::coroutines::detail::push_coroutine_impl<void>::push(): Assertion `! is_running()' failed

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost-asio, boost-coroutine

### Subject

[This POC app](https://github.com/Al2Klimov/grumpycathttpd/tree/67a26e4d9b97c27e24d5c663433a59225532dca3) uses Boost ASIO with coroutines to serve HTTP requests. Once a request has been read completely, the connection handler outsources the actual request handling into a separate thread pool for CPU-bound ops and the connection handler coroutine gets paused. Once the response is done, that coroutine gets resumed to send it.

### Problem

While being tested with `wrk -d 30 -c 100 -t 100 http://127.0.0.1:8910/` the app fails sooner or later with:

```
grumpycathttpd: /usr/include/boost/coroutine/detail/push_coroutine_impl.hpp:258: void boost::coroutines::detail::push_coroutine_impl<void>::push(): Assertion `! is_running()' failed.
```

### My Questions

1. Is the app's concept (ASIO thread pool with coroutines + CPU-bound thread pool with queue) possible/realistic at all?
2. If yes: What exactly am I doing wrong while pausing/resuming the coroutine? Shall I not use `async_completion`, `completion_handler` and `asio_handler_invoke` like the boost libs themselves do?

### Code

AFAIK I should post the app's code – so here it is... I hope it doesn't matter that there are 223 lines.

IMO the important lines are 160, 193-198, 92-102 and 106-109.

```cpp
/* 1 */ #include <condition_variable>
/* 2 */ using std::condition_variable;
/* 3 */ 
/* 4 */ #include <exception>
/* 5 */ using std::exception;
/* 6 */ 
/* 7 */ #include <functional>
/* 8 */ using std::function;
/* 9 */ 
/* 10 */ #include <iostream>
/* 11 */ using std::cout;
/* 12 */ using std::endl;
/* 13 */ 
/* 14 */ #include <limits>
/* 15 */ using std::numeric_limits;
/* 16 */ 
/* 17 */ #include <memory>
/* 18 */ using std::make_shared;
/* 19 */ using std::shared_ptr;
/* 20 */ 
/* 21 */ #include <mutex>
/* 22 */ using std::mutex;
/* 23 */ using std::unique_lock;
/* 24 */ 
/* 25 */ #include <queue>
/* 26 */ using std::queue;
/* 27 */ 
/* 28 */ #include <thread>
/* 29 */ using std::thread;
/* 30 */ 
/* 31 */ #include <utility>
/* 32 */ using std::move;
/* 33 */ 
/* 34 */ #include <vector>
/* 35 */ using std::vector;
/* 36 */ 
/* 37 */ #include <boost/asio/async_result.hpp>
/* 38 */ using boost::asio::async_completion;
/* 39 */ 
/* 40 */ #include <boost/asio/buffer.hpp>
/* 41 */ using boost::asio::mutable_buffer;
/* 42 */ 
/* 43 */ #include <boost/asio/buffered_stream.hpp>
/* 44 */ using boost::asio::buffered_stream;
/* 45 */ 
/* 46 */ #include <boost/asio/handler_invoke_hook.hpp>
/* 47 */ using boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke;
/* 48 */ 
/* 49 */ #include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
/* 50 */ using boost::asio::io_service;
/* 51 */ 
/* 52 */ #include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
/* 53 */ using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
/* 54 */ 
/* 55 */ #include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
/* 56 */ using boost::asio::spawn;
/* 57 */ 
/* 58 */ #include <boost/asio/yield.hpp>
/* 59 */ using boost::asio::yield_context;
/* 60 */ 
/* 61 */ #include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
/* 62 */ namespace beast = boost::beast;
/* 63 */ 
/* 64 */ #include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
/* 65 */ namespace http = beast::http;
/* 66 */ 
/* 67 */ #include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
/* 68 */ using boost::system::error_code;
/* 69 */ 
/* 70 */ 
/* 71 */ class work_queue {
/* 72 */ public:
/* 73 */    work_queue(io_service& io) : io(io), pool((vector<thread>::size_type)(thread::hardware_concurrency())), stop(false) {
/* 74 */        for (auto& thrd : pool) {
/* 75 */            thrd = thread([this](){ run(); });
/* 76 */        }
/* 77 */    }
/* 78 */ 
/* 79 */    ~work_queue() {
/* 80 */        {
/* 81 */            unique_lock<mutex> ul (mtx);
/* 82 */            stop = true;
/* 83 */            cond_var.notify_all();
/* 84 */        }
/* 85 */ 
/* 86 */        for (auto& thrd : pool) {
/* 87 */            thrd.join();
/* 88 */        }
/* 89 */    }
/* 90 */ 
/* 91 */    template<class Handler>
/* 92 */    void async_run(function<void()> task, Handler&& handler) {
/* 93 */        async_completion<Handler, void(error_code)> init(handler);
/* 94 */ 
/* 95 */        {
/* 96 */            auto completion_handler (make_shared<decltype(init.completion_handler)>(init.completion_handler));
/* 97 */            unique_lock<mutex> ul (mtx);
/* 98 */            tasks.emplace(enqueued_task({move(task), [completion_handler](){ asio_handler_invoke(*completion_handler); }}));
/* 99 */            cond_var.notify_all();
/* 100 */       }
/* 101 */ 
/* 102 */       init.result.get();
/* 103 */   }
/* 104 */ 
/* 105 */ private:
/* 106 */   struct enqueued_task {
/* 107 */       function<void()> task;
/* 108 */       function<void()> on_done;
/* 109 */   };
/* 110 */ 
/* 111 */   mutex mtx;
/* 112 */   condition_variable cond_var;
/* 113 */   io_service& io;
/* 114 */   queue<enqueued_task> tasks;
/* 115 */   vector<thread> pool;
/* 116 */   bool stop;
/* 117 */ 
/* 118 */   void run() {
/* 119 */       unique_lock<mutex> ul (mtx);
/* 120 */ 
/* 121 */       while (!stop) {
/* 122 */           while (!tasks.empty()) {
/* 123 */               auto task (move(tasks.front()));
/* 124 */               tasks.pop();
/* 125 */ 
/* 126 */               ul.unlock();
/* 127 */ 
/* 128 */               try {
/* 129 */                   task.task();
/* 130 */               } catch (...) {
/* 131 */               }
/* 132 */ 
/* 133 */               io.post(move(task.on_done));
/* 134 */ 
/* 135 */               ul.lock();
/* 136 */           }
/* 137 */ 
/* 138 */           cond_var.wait(ul);
/* 139 */       }
/* 140 */   }
/* 141 */ };
/* 142 */ 
/* 143 */ int main() {
/* 144 */   vector<thread> pool ((vector<thread>::size_type)(thread::hardware_concurrency()));
/* 145 */   io_service io;
/* 146 */   work_queue wq (io);
/* 147 */   tcp::acceptor acceptor (io);
/* 148 */   tcp::endpoint endpoint (tcp::v6(), 8910);
/* 149 */ 
/* 150 */   acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
/* 151 */   acceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
/* 152 */   acceptor.bind(endpoint);
/* 153 */   acceptor.listen(numeric_limits<int>::max());
/* 154 */ 
/* 155 */   spawn(acceptor.get_io_context(), [&acceptor, &wq](yield_context yc) {
/* 156 */       for (;;) {
/* 157 */           shared_ptr<tcp::socket> peer (new tcp::socket(acceptor.get_io_context()));
/* 158 */           acceptor.async_accept(*peer, yc);
/* 159 */ 
/* 160 */           spawn(acceptor.get_io_context(), [peer, &wq](yield_context yc) {
/* 161 */               try {
/* 162 */                   {
/* 163 */                       auto remote (peer->remote_endpoint());
/* 164 */                       cout << "I has conn: [" << remote.address().to_string() << "]:" << remote.port() << endl;
/* 165 */                   }
/* 166 */ 
/* 167 */                   buffered_stream<decltype(*peer)> iobuf (*peer);
/* 168 */ 
/* 169 */                   iobuf.async_fill(yc);
/* 170 */ 
/* 171 */                   if (iobuf.in_avail() > 0) {
/* 172 */                       char first_char;
/* 173 */ 
/* 174 */                       {
/* 175 */                           mutable_buffer first_char_buf (&first_char, 1);
/* 176 */                           iobuf.peek(first_char_buf);
/* 177 */                       }
/* 178 */ 
/* 179 */                       if ('0' <= first_char && first_char <= '9') {
/* 180 */                           cout << "I has JSON-RPC!" << endl;
/* 181 */                       } else {
/* 182 */                           beast::flat_buffer buf;
/* 183 */ 
/* 184 */                           for (;;) {
/* 185 */                               http::request<http::string_body> req;
/* 186 */ 
/* 187 */                               http::async_read(iobuf, buf, req, yc);
/* 188 */ 
/* 189 */                               cout << "I has req: '" << req.body() << '\'' << endl;
/* 190 */ 
/* 191 */                               http::response<http::string_body> res;
/* 192 */ 
/* 193 */                               wq.async_run([&req, &res](){
/* 194 */                                   res.result(http::status::internal_server_error);
/* 195 */                                   res.set(http::field::content_type, "text/plain");
/* 196 */                                   res.set(http::field::content_length, "36");
/* 197 */                                   res.body() = "I like onions. They make people cry.";
/* 198 */                               }, yc);
/* 199 */ 
/* 200 */                               http::async_write(iobuf, res, yc);
/* 201 */                               iobuf.async_flush(yc);
/* 202 */ 
/* 203 */                               cout << "I has res." << endl;
/* 204 */                           }
/* 205 */                       }
/* 206 */                   }
/* 207 */ 
/* 208 */                   peer->shutdown(peer->shutdown_both);
/* 209 */               } catch (const exception& e) {
/* 210 */                   cout << "I has exception: " << e.what() << endl;
/* 211 */               }
/* 212 */           });
/* 213 */       }
/* 214 */   });
/* 215 */ 
/* 216 */   for (auto& thrd : pool) {
/* 217 */       thrd = thread([&io](){ io.run(); });
/* 218 */   }
/* 219 */ 
/* 220 */   for (auto& thrd : pool) {
/* 221 */       thrd.join();
/* 222 */   }
/* 223 */ }
```

### Edit #1: Backtrace

```
...
Assertion failed: (! is_running()), function push, file CENSORED/include/boost/coroutine/detail/push_coroutine_impl.hpp, line 258.
Process 43694 stopped
* thread #2, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00007fff7567123e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
->  0x7fff7567123e <+10>: jae    0x7fff75671248            ; <+20>
    0x7fff75671240 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff75671243 <+15>: jmp    0x7fff7566b3b7            ; cerror_nocancel
    0x7fff75671248 <+20>: retq   
Target 0: (grumpycathttpd) stopped.
(lldb) bt all
  thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread'
    frame #0: 0x00007fff7566d94e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__ulock_wait + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff7572970a libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_join + 356
    frame #2: 0x00007fff72c48978 libc++.1.dylib`std::__1::thread::join() + 24
    frame #3: 0x00000001000039b8 grumpycathttpd`main + 1544
    frame #4: 0x00007fff75531ed9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #5: 0x00007fff75531ed9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
* thread #2, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff7567123e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff75727c1c libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 285
    frame #2: 0x00007fff755da1c9 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #3: 0x00007fff755a2868 libsystem_c.dylib`__assert_rtn + 320
    frame #4: 0x00000001000680ea grumpycathttpd`boost::coroutines::detail::push_coroutine_impl<void>::push() + 122
    frame #5: 0x000000010000884c grumpycathttpd`boost::asio::detail::completion_handler<std::__1::function<void ()> >::do_complete(void*, boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) + 156
    frame #6: 0x00000001000691e6 grumpycathttpd`boost::asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock&, boost::asio::detail::scheduler_thread_info&, boost::system::error_code const&) + 822
    frame #7: 0x0000000100068cb2 grumpycathttpd`boost::asio::detail::scheduler::run(boost::system::error_code&) + 194
    frame #8: 0x0000000100068aea grumpycathttpd`void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, main::$_1> >(void*) + 74
    frame #9: 0x00007fff75725305 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 126
    frame #10: 0x00007fff7572826f libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 70
    frame #11: 0x00007fff75724415 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
  thread #3
    frame #0: 0x00007fff7566e7de libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff75728593 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 724
    frame #2: 0x00007fff72c07bda libc++.1.dylib`std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 18
    frame #3: 0x00000001000081f4 grumpycathttpd`work_queue::run() + 644
    frame #4: 0x0000000100007efd grumpycathttpd`void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, work_queue::work_queue(boost::asio::io_context&)::'lambda'()> >(void*) + 45
    frame #5: 0x00007fff75725305 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 126
    frame #6: 0x00007fff7572826f libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 70
    frame #7: 0x00007fff75724415 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
  thread #4
    frame #0: 0x00007fff7566e7de libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff75728593 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 724
    frame #2: 0x00007fff72c07bda libc++.1.dylib`std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 18
    frame #3: 0x00000001000081f4 grumpycathttpd`work_queue::run() + 644
    frame #4: 0x0000000100007efd grumpycathttpd`void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, work_queue::work_queue(boost::asio::io_context&)::'lambda'()> >(void*) + 45
    frame #5: 0x00007fff75725305 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 126
    frame #6: 0x00007fff7572826f libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 70
    frame #7: 0x00007fff75724415 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
  thread #5
    frame #0: 0x00007fff7566e7de libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff75728593 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 724
    frame #2: 0x00007fff72c07bda libc++.1.dylib`std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 18
    frame #3: 0x00000001000081f4 grumpycathttpd`work_queue::run() + 644
    frame #4: 0x0000000100007efd grumpycathttpd`void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, work_queue::work_queue(boost::asio::io_context&)::'lambda'()> >(void*) + 45
    frame #5: 0x00007fff75725305 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 126
    frame #6: 0x00007fff7572826f libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 70
    frame #7: 0x00007fff75724415 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
  thread #6
    frame #0: 0x00007fff7566e7de libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff75728593 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 724
    frame #2: 0x00007fff72c07bda libc++.1.dylib`std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 18
    frame #3: 0x00000001000081f4 grumpycathttpd`work_queue::run() + 644
    frame #4: 0x0000000100007efd grumpycathttpd`void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, work_queue::work_queue(boost::asio::io_context&)::'lambda'()> >(void*) + 45
    frame #5: 0x00007fff75725305 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 126
    frame #6: 0x00007fff7572826f libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 70
    frame #7: 0x00007fff75724415 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
  thread #7
    frame #0: 0x00007fff7566de76 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff75725d6c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_wait + 96
    frame #2: 0x00007fff757234b7 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow + 226
    frame #3: 0x00000001000696fb grumpycathttpd`boost::asio::detail::kqueue_reactor::run(long, boost::asio::detail::op_queue<boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation>&) + 379
    frame #4: 0x0000000100069070 grumpycathttpd`boost::asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock&, boost::asio::detail::scheduler_thread_info&, boost::system::error_code const&) + 448
    frame #5: 0x0000000100068cb2 grumpycathttpd`boost::asio::detail::scheduler::run(boost::system::error_code&) + 194
    frame #6: 0x0000000100068aea grumpycathttpd`void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, main::$_1> >(void*) + 74
    frame #7: 0x00007fff75725305 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 126
    frame #8: 0x00007fff7572826f libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 70
    frame #9: 0x00007fff75724415 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
  thread #8
    frame #0: 0x00007fff756706e6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__sendmsg + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000100037de4 grumpycathttpd`boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::non_blocking_send(int, iovec const*, unsigned long, int, boost::system::error_code&, unsigned long&) + 100
    frame #2: 0x0000000100037d4f grumpycathttpd`boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_send_op_base<boost::asio::const_buffers_1>::do_perform(boost::asio::detail::reactor_op*) + 63
    frame #3: 0x000000010000fb00 grumpycathttpd`boost::asio::detail::kqueue_reactor::start_op(int, int, boost::asio::detail::kqueue_reactor::descriptor_state*&, boost::asio::detail::reactor_op*, bool, bool) + 304
    frame #4: 0x000000010000f927 grumpycathttpd`boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::start_op(boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::base_implementation_type&, int, boost::asio::detail::reactor_op*, bool, bool, bool) + 103
    frame #5: 0x0000000100057c17 grumpycathttpd`void boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::async_send<boost::asio::const_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::mutable_buffer const*, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::asio::detail::buffered_flush_handler<boost::asio::detail::coro_handler<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor>, unsigned long> > > >(boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::base_implementation_type&, boost::asio::const_buffers_1 const&, int, boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::mutable_buffer const*, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::asio::detail::buffered_flush_handler<boost::asio::detail::coro_handler<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor>, unsigned long> > >&) + 135
    frame #6: 0x00000001000579b7 grumpycathttpd`void boost::asio::detail::start_write_buffer_sequence_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::mutable_buffer const*, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::asio::detail::buffered_flush_handler<boost::asio::detail::coro_handler<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor>, unsigned long> > >(boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1 const&, boost::asio::mutable_buffer const* const&, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::asio::detail::buffered_flush_handler<boost::asio::detail::coro_handler<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor>, unsigned long> >&) + 231
    frame #7: 0x000000010005778d grumpycathttpd`boost::asio::async_result<std::__1::decay<boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor> >&>::type, void (boost::system::error_code, unsigned long)>::return_type boost::asio::buffered_write_stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&>::async_flush<boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor> >&>(boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor> >&&&) + 573
    frame #8: 0x0000000100010cc8 grumpycathttpd`boost::coroutines::detail::push_coroutine_object<boost::coroutines::pull_coroutine<void>, void, boost::asio::detail::coro_entry_point<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> >, main::$_0::operator()(boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor> >) const::'lambda'(boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor> >)>&, boost::coroutines::basic_standard_stack_allocator<boost::coroutines::stack_traits> >::run() + 2040
    frame #9: 0x00000001000104d0 grumpycathttpd`void boost::coroutines::detail::trampoline_push_void<boost::coroutines::detail::push_coroutine_object<boost::coroutines::pull_coroutine<void>, void, boost::asio::detail::coro_entry_point<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> >, main::$_0::operator()(boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor> >) const::'lambda'(boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor> >)>&, boost::coroutines::basic_standard_stack_allocator<boost::coroutines::stack_traits> > >(boost::context::detail::transfer_t) + 96
    frame #10: 0x000000010021832f libboost_context-mt.dylib`trampoline + 3
  thread #9
    frame #0: 0x00007fff756706e6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__sendmsg + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000100037de4 grumpycathttpd`boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::non_blocking_send(int, iovec const*, unsigned long, int, boost::system::error_code&, unsigned long&) + 100
    frame #2: 0x0000000100037d4f grumpycathttpd`boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_send_op_base<boost::asio::const_buffers_1>::do_perform(boost::asio::detail::reactor_op*) + 63
    frame #3: 0x000000010000fb00 grumpycathttpd`boost::asio::detail::kqueue_reactor::start_op(int, int, boost::asio::detail::kqueue_reactor::descriptor_state*&, boost::asio::detail::reactor_op*, bool, bool) + 304
    frame #4: 0x000000010000f927 grumpycathttpd`boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::start_op(boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::base_implementation_type&, int, boost::asio::detail::reactor_op*, bool, bool, bool) + 103
    frame #5: 0x0000000100057c17 grumpycathttpd`void boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::async_send<boost::asio::const_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::mutable_buffer const*, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::asio::detail::buffered_flush_handler<boost::asio::detail::coro_handler<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor>, unsigned long> > > >(boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::base_implementation_type&, boost::asio::const_buffers_1 const&, int, boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::mutable_buffer const*, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::asio::detail::buffered_flush_handler<boost::asio::detail::coro_handler<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor>, unsigned long> > >&) + 135
    frame #6: 0x00000001000579b7 grumpycathttpd`void boost::asio::detail::start_write_buffer_sequence_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::mutable_buffer const*, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::asio::detail::buffered_flush_handler<boost::asio::detail::coro_handler<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor>, unsigned long> > >(boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1 const&, boost::asio::mutable_buffer const* const&, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::asio::detail::buffered_flush_handler<boost::asio::detail::coro_handler<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor>, unsigned long> >&) + 231
    frame #7: 0x000000010005778d grumpycathttpd`boost::asio::async_result<std::__1::decay<boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor> >&>::type, void (boost::system::error_code, unsigned long)>::return_type boost::asio::buffered_write_stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&>::async_flush<boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor> >&>(boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor> >&&&) + 573
    frame #8: 0x0000000100010cc8 grumpycathttpd`boost::coroutines::detail::push_coroutine_object<boost::coroutines::pull_coroutine<void>, void, boost::asio::detail::coro_entry_point<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> >, main::$_0::operator()(boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor> >) const::'lambda'(boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor> >)>&, boost::coroutines::basic_standard_stack_allocator<boost::coroutines::stack_traits> >::run() + 2040
    frame #9: 0x00000001000104d0 grumpycathttpd`void boost::coroutines::detail::trampoline_push_void<boost::coroutines::detail::push_coroutine_object<boost::coroutines::pull_coroutine<void>, void, boost::asio::detail::coro_entry_point<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> >, main::$_0::operator()(boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor> >) const::'lambda'(boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::executor_binder<void (*)(), boost::asio::executor> >)>&, boost::coroutines::basic_standard_stack_allocator<boost::coroutines::stack_traits> > >(boost::context::detail::transfer_t) + 96
    frame #10: 0x000000010021832f libboost_context-mt.dylib`trampoline + 3
(lldb)
```

### Edit #2

It seems one of my errors was in `work_queue#async_run()` which had to be:

```cpp
    template<class Handler>
    void async_run(function<void()> task, Handler&& handler) {
        async_completion<Handler, void(error_code)> init(handler);

        {
            auto completion_handler (init.completion_handler);
            unique_lock<mutex> ul (mtx);
            tasks.emplace(enqueued_task({move(task), [completion_handler](){
                auto completion_handler_ (completion_handler);
                asio_handler_invoke(completion_handler_, &completion_handler_);
            }}));
            cond_var.notify_all();
        }

        init.result.get();
    }
```

But this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong, partially also due to the complexity of the issue. Anyhow, there are two questions that I'd look at: Firstly, what's the backtrace when the assertion fires? This should answer whether there's some kind of invalid use right there or whether the invalid state was only detected there. The second question is when the affected object was last touched and from which thread.

Comment: Why don't you simply copy and paste one of the Beast HTTP asynchronous server examples which use coroutines and then modify that? They already work. Such as this one:
https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/1a80dd4560011cad2f2aa56bf7ee55f8fea752a6/example/http/server/coro/http_server_coro.cpp

Comment: My POC app works too... if I don't use any separate thread pool.